# Reactnative: undefined response when fetiching data from localhost symfony API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

I have an app build with reactnative, it is running on my local pc, and i would like to fetch and display data from a local symfony api that i have running.

The reactnative code is fetching from my local pc ip, and the symfony port/route:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isLoading: true,
    dataSource: [],
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  return fetch('http://10.161.170.86:8000/api/hardwarePlacement')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.ok);
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(response.ok);
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: responseJson.hardwarePlacements,
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });
}
```

And the json data i get from my symfony API looks like so, when i get it from postman or go directly through the browser:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Bryggers","createdDate":{"date":"2023-02-08 15:14:12.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"},"editedDate":{"date":"2023-02-14 13:57:07.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"}},{"id":2,"name":"Stue","createdDate":{"date":"2023-02-08 21:52:46.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"},"editedDate":{"date":"2023-02-08 21:52:46.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"}},{"id":3,"name":"Stue","createdDate":{"date":"2023-02-14 13:57:10.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"},"editedDate":{"date":"2023-02-14 13:57:10.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"}}]
```

The error i get in my terminal is:

```
[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.json')]
```

If i try with fetching data from an public URL instead, it works fine, it is only from getching data from localhost url, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return from the first `then`

```
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.ok);
    return response
  })  
  .then((response) => response.json())
```